# Does it matter how often units are sampled for fixed effects models?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, econometrics, causality, fixed-effects-model

Suppose I am building a fixed effects models and my observations are every second. However the data does not fit into memory. If I were to aggregate the observations weekly or monthly, would that make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decision to aggregate your observations at the minute, hour, day, week or month level depends on your context. Suppose that what you're interested in is the effect of a covariate on a given outcome, aggregating the data kills the variability in your treatment and your outcome that comes within the unit of aggregation. At the end, what matters is the frequency of the phenomenon you want to capture in your outcome and your covariate of interest.

For instance, imagine what you observe is the consumption of electricity of a given household every second. If you interested in the effect of a tax reform on consumption, you can safely aggregate the data at the day, week or even month level, as the propagation of the reform on consumption is not likely to be observed immediately. Conversely, imagine that you are interested in the effect of, say, TV commercials, which happen at some particular times and are observed every hour of the day. Then, you probably want to keep the data at the minute, or even the second level to leverage the variability at a fine level.